# dplyr filter () ignores the rows with the value 0, how to change that

Tags: r, dplyr

In my case, I need the filter function to consider the rows with value 0, but it ignores that.

So I have this data attached and I want to filter out the values of flowers separately for s1 and s2 names. My table is case1

[image]

```
  s1= filter(case1, Flower,Name=="s1")
  s2= filter(case1, Flower,Name=="s2")
```

This statement runs well, but it ignores the 0 values. I also want to include the 0 values in my analysis. So, how shall I make it to accept that.

EDIT following the comment

```
Flower,Name,Pl
10, s1, WI
10, s1, WO
30, s1, EI
0,  s1, EO
0,  s2, EI
0,  s2, EO
0,  s1, WI
0,  s2, WO
0,  s2, WO
3,  s2, WI
50, s2, EI
0,  s1, EO
0,  s1, EI
```

Expected output:

For s1 all values of s1  something like this(including rows with Flower 0)

```
Flower, Name, Pl
10, s1, WI
10, s1, WO
30, s1, EI
0,  s1, EO
```

For s2, all values of s2, something like that

```
Flower, Name, Pl
0,  s2, WO
0,  s2, WO
3,  s2, WI
50, s2, EI
```

Comment: Try `filter(case1, Name=='s1')`

Comment: @akrun Hello,  I have included your suggestions. The reason I put image is just because it is easy to understand the data. It is difficult to present the data otherwise on this portal.

Comment: Can you check the output in the solution below.  I guess the output you showed didn't include all the '0' rows

Comment: no, as that was the expected output , no the real one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do

```
filter(case1, Name=='s1')
#  Flower Name PI
#1     10   s1 WI
#2     10   s1 WO
#3     30   s1 EI
#4      0   s1 EO
#5      0   s1 WI
#6      0   s1 EO
#7      0   s1 EI
```

By using 'Flower' inside the `filter`, the '0' values are coerced to 'FALSE' and all others 'TRUE'.

Comment: Now thats interesting, but why does that happen?

Comment: user3050590 It would be like `filter(case1, Flower!=0 & Name=='s1')`.  As I mentioned, by using the variable `Flower` in `filter`, the column got converted to logical 'TRUE/FALSE`